# Where could I ask questions about the Indonesian language?

Tags: online-learning, indonesian

*Indonesian Language Stack Exchange* is not a thing. Do you know any places where learners can ask questions about the Indonesian language?

Comment: Any reasonable reasons for downvoting, downvoter? This is absolutely on-topic.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question but I suspect the downvote was because "good" is simply too subjective. Could you rephrase your question to include more objective criteria instead of "good"?

Comment: @Tsundoku I see; it was just a filler word. If that’s the case, I just removed the “good” as it doesn’t necessarily need to be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen Hinative used to answer both simple and complex questions about Indonesian.
https://hinative.com/

The format isn't as good as a Bahasa Indonesia stackexchange would be, but it seems ok.

Formerly, there were the duolingo forums, but apparently they've been nuked out of existence with little explanation :(

Selamat belajar...